# AngularJS: Changing ng-animate css on-the-fly

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I working on a multi-stage-web-form with AngularJS, as you can see at the following example:

http://codepen.io/kwakwak/full/kvEig

When you click the "Next" button, the form slides right, but when you click the "Back" button, the form isn't slides left as it should, I need to change the "ng-animate" css when the "Back" button is clicked.

How should I accomplish that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your controller you can set a variable that determines the direction of the animation.. So something like this (pseudocode):

```
$scope.update = function() {
   $scope.direction = 1;
}

$scope.backTo = function() {
   $scope.direction = 0;
}
```

In your html you'd surround the areas that are animating:

```
<div ng-class="{forward: direction, backward: !direction}">
   your animated stuff here
</div>
```

Now just setup your css rules:

```
.forward .animate-switch.ng-leave{  
  left:0;
}
/* hide */
.forward  .animate-switch.ng-leave.ng-leave-active{ 
  left:-100%;
}
/* show entering slide  */
/* hide */
.forward .animate-switch.ng-enter {
  left:100%;
}
/* show */
.forward .animate-switch.ng-enter.ng-enter-active { 
  left:0;
}

.backward  animate-switch.ng-leave{  
  /* etc */
}
```

Here is a demo from your code pen: http://codepen.io/sbosell/pen/rKJal